# Object doesn't take a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#

I have generated this simplified version of my problem:

```
public class Variable
{
    public Variable(string s, int i)
    {

    }
    public Variable(string str) : base(str, 0) // error here
    {

    }
}
```

Clearly I have a constructor that take 2 arguments.
But the error is saying that I don't.

I am confused.

I am using **.NET Standard 2.0**

Please ask for any additional clarification.

Comment: `: this(str, 0)` instead of `: base(str, 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`base` class (`object` in your case) *doesn't have* such a constructor

```
 object(string s, int i)
```

But your *current* class `this` does have the required constructor:

```
public class Variable
{
    public Variable(string s, int i)
    {

    }

    public Variable(string str) : this(str, 0) // current class constructor call
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for saving my day.. I knew only about `base()` to overload contructors in c#.. Is it (use of `this`) only in .net-standard or everywhere in c# ?

Comment: @Muzib: `this` as a current class constructor can be used *everywhere* in c#

Answer (score 3):

```
: base(str, 0)
```

is calling the `Object` constructor which doesn't have one for 2 parameters.

use this instead

```
: this(str, 0)
```